# Disable leaflet map using blockUI in checkboxes' layercontrol

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm developing a react app using leaflet and i've a problem with the layercontrol, specifically with the checkboxes functionality hiding/showing the layer.

To contextualize, the app makes an AJAX request after each radiobutton select, to fill some layers in dependency of the option selected, and hide/show those layers using the checkboxes. I'm using the [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) to lock the map and prevent the user from manipulation the map. This plugin works fine with the AJAX calls (as i expected from the documentation), that is to say to each radiobutton, but when i tried to do the same in the leaflet methods
the lock screen appears late, once the layer is already loaded.

In my try to debug it, i noted that there is a bit of 'dead time' from the 'click' in the checkbox until the load of the layer with the painted polygons. I think that this is the key for the solution but i tried a lot of things to fix this and nothing works.

My aim is to put the lock screen just before the click on the checkbox, while the layer is loading, until after the layer appears on the map.

I made [an functional example of the app in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mmvn7vlqkp) in case someone would help me. Any comments/ideas should be grateful, i've been in this a loooot of time.

Comment: Why are you "blocking" the UI in the first place?

Comment: @IvanSanchez To avoid the user interaction while the layer is loading data or hiding/showing, preventing crashes, and showing an decent waiting screen to the user. Any other way to get these aims, fixing the 'dead time' if its possible, would be great

Comment: This is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't really want to block the UI; you want to prevent race conditions, you thought that blocking the UI was a good way to prevent race conditions, and you had problems with that.

Please edit your question to reflect this, and specify if the AJAX queries are always to the same URL, or if there is some dynamic parameter to them.

Comment: @IvanSanchez thanks for the reply. I'll keep it in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the root cause of your "*bit of 'dead time'*" is that you display [GeoJSON data which weighs 26+MB](https://gist.github.com/luispina/ecc0d3e038803473f29878ad4852df5b?short_path=8a01837)…

When you tick the overlay checkbox in the [Leaflet Layers Control](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#control-layers), the browser computes the rendering for a few seconds (depending on the Client performance), *synchronously*, so no event fires in the meantime. If you pay close attention, you will see that even the browser UI does not have time displaying the "tick" in the checkbox.

It is understandable that you would like to provide some feedback to the user, so that they know their click has been taken into account and the CPU is running crazy to display your data. And also prevent them from trying to perform other actions, which could just make the situation worse…

With the standard Layers Control, unfortunately you cannot "hook" in the process to display your jQuery BlockUI overlay between the user tick and Leaflet trying to render your GeoJSON data.

However you have several easy workarounds:

- implement your own "Control" so that you have control of what the checkbox does when the user ticks it: render your BlockUI overlay first, then add the GeoJSON group to the map.
- Use an "intermediate" empty dummy layer that you provide to the Layers Control, so that it does not need any processing being added to the map, but listen to the map's [`"overlayadd"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-overlayadd) and [`"overlayremove"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-overlayremove) events to "manually" add / remove your GeoJSON group to the map, *after* having rendered your BlockUI: (example with light data, but look at the bottom of the post for an example with heavy data)

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

// This would be actually your heavy GeoJSON Layer Group.
var polygon = L.circle([48.86, 2.35], {
  radius: 2000
});

// This is an empty layer, just to feed it into the Layers Control and listen to its state.
var dummyLayer = L.featureGroup();

L.control.layers(null, {
  'Dummy Layer': dummyLayer, // Use this to implement your BlockUI (see below event listeners)
  'Polygon': polygon // If you add directly your heavy layer, you cannot execute code before the browser "hangs" when it renders.
}, {
  collapsed: false
}).addTo(map);

map.on('overlayadd', function(event) {
  var layer = event.layer;

  if (layer === dummyLayer) {
    $.blockUI({
      message: '<h1>RENDERING crazy heavy data...</h1>'
    });
    // Slight delay to make sure BlockUI has time rendering the overlay.
    setTimeout(() => {
      polygon.addTo(map);
      $.unblockUI();
    }, 200);
  }
});
map.on('overlayremove', function(event) {
  var layer = event.layer;

  if (layer === dummyLayer) {
    // Slight delay for Leaflet to finish checking the Layers Control state.
    // That is just an artifact due to having added polygon also to the Layers Control.
    // In your case you would probably not add it to the Control,
    // so you should not need such delay.
    setTimeout(() => {
      polygon.remove();
    }, 100);
  }
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/block-ui@2.70.1/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

Plunker with your actual heavy GeoJSON data: https://plnkr.co/edit/EhoRzDaqClZ6sGgRVVPu?p=preview

Comment: i used the second idea and it works so perfect that i almost cried of happiness...days and days trying it with no results. Thanks so much!